# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, use-state, readonly

For the code I am currently working on, I have a very complicated array filled with objects.
The point of this page is to change one property of one object in the array at a time, and as is such, the entire array needs to be updated to carry out that change.
The array is initialized as so...

```
const [allDevices, setAllDevices] = useState(initialDeviceNames)
```

where intialDeviceNames will either be a populated object fetched from a query, or an empty array if there is no matching instance. That will look like this...

**note that an empty object (if none with a matching date value is found) will have every number property set to `{id: null, name: "No Driver Selected"}`**

```
0:
0: {id: 'dfebc7ce-ea4b-48d4-9fd9-7c2d02572e40', name: 'DANIEL STITT', type: 'Vehicle'}
1: {id: '64303dc1-0ba6-43bb-a25a-9885f9e8f2e3', name: 'KENNETH WILLIFORD', type: 'Vehicle'}
2: {id: '1a778957-b679-401b-972d-aeb32f84e667', name: 'JASON PITSNOGLE', type: 'Vehicle'}
3: {id: '1fcc9d60-fc6f-4e34-b5ab-c64d5ea8778a', name: 'VIRGINIA SHADE', type: 'Vehicle'}
4: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
5: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
6: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
amount: 6
name: "Vehicle"
remaining_drivers: (60) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
0: {id: '1a778957-b679-401b-972d-aeb32f84e667', name: 'JASON PITSNOGLE', type: 'iPad'}
1: {id: 'dfebc7ce-ea4b-48d4-9fd9-7c2d02572e40', name: 'DANIEL STITT', type: 'iPad'}
2: {id: '1fcc9d60-fc6f-4e34-b5ab-c64d5ea8778a', name: 'VIRGINIA SHADE', type: 'iPad'}
3: {id: '203726da-dba7-4f74-9d86-919d6a02a282', name: 'DONNA HAGGERTY', type: 'iPad'}
4: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
5: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
6: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
7: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
8: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
9: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
10: {id: null, name: 'No Driver Assigned'}
amount: 10
name: "iPad"
remaining_drivers: (60) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

So updating this one at a time is clearly complicated. I have to find the right object in the array, then find the right number property inside that object, change it, and then get the whole state to update. The code I had for this worked until I added some pre-population functionality. The code for updating any of these single properties will be shown below...

```
const handleDriverSelection = (driver, index, superIndex, deviceObj) => {
        // If driver is the same 
        if (allDevices[superIndex][index].name == `${driver.firstname} ${driver.lastname}`){
        }

        // If active driver is empty
        else if (allDevices[superIndex][index].name == "No Driver Assigned" || allDevices[superIndex][index] == 'undefined'){
            console.log(allDevices)
            let newArray = [...allDevices]

            // The specific device drop selected will be set equal the the driver clicked
            newArray[superIndex][index] = {
                name: `${driver.firstname} ${driver.lastname}`, 
                id: driver.id,
                type: deviceObj.name
            }

            // This removes the driver from the list of remaining driver
            newArray[superIndex].remaining_drivers = newArray[superIndex].remaining_drivers.filter( (remDriver) => {
                if (driver != remDriver){
                    return remDriver
                }
            })


            // This sets the state
            setAllDevices(newArray)
        }

        // if active driver exists but is NOT the one inputted
        else if (allDevices[superIndex][index].name != "No Driver Assigned" ){
            console.log(allDevices)
            let newArray = [...allDevices]

            // This finds the driver that was previously selected and adds him/her back to the remaining list
            // For each driver...
            user.drivers.forEach( (dspDriver) => {

                // if the driver iterated == the driver that was previously selected
                if (allDevices[superIndex][index].name == `${dspDriver.firstname} ${dspDriver.lastname}`){

                    // Adds the driver to remaining drivers
                    newArray[superIndex].remaining_drivers = [...newArray[superIndex].remaining_drivers, dspDriver]

                    // Sets the current drop state to the driver selected
                    newArray[superIndex][index] = {
                        name: `${driver.firstname} ${driver.lastname}`, 
                        id: driver.id, 
                        type: deviceObj.name 
                    }

                    // Removes the driver selected from the list of remaining drivers
                    newArray[superIndex].remaining_drivers = newArray[superIndex].remaining_drivers.filter( (remDriver, index) => {
                        if (driver != remDriver){
                            return remDriver
                        }
                    })
                    setAllDevices(newArray)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

This is where I'm getting very confused-- through the line

```
let newArray = [...allDevices]
```

I would think that newArray creates an array with the exact same contents of `allDevices`. `allDevices`, since it is a local state, is read-only. I understand this. I also understand that had I wrote `let newArray = allDevices` that `newArray` would also be read only since it would not be a new array but rather just a different variable pointing to the value of `allDevices`.
As is such, I have no idea why this ISNT working, since `newArray` shouldn't be read-only at all. The code I added had a multitude of complicated useEffects to handle querying, mutating and refreshing, so I can't see how it would effect the code I showed above, especially since `newArray` doesn't exist anywhere but this code.

Answer (score 0):

If I went a step further in creating a new identical array, furthering it from the original read-only array, it worked. This means to say I changed

```
let newArray = [...allDevices]
```

to

```
let newArray = []
   allDevices.forEach( (device, index) => {
       newArray[index] = {...device}
   })
```

Seems a little redundant, but I suppose the issue was that **even though I created a read-and-write duplicate of the array which contained the objects, I didn't explicitly create a read-and-write version of each object, which, as a part of the initial array, must have also been read only**